# CSS: On Hover - How can I change css attributes of a selector's child?

Tags: css, hover

I have these smaller banners where I want to change some of the styling attributes inside of my "A" tag.

```
<a href="#">
   <h2>Heading</h2>
   <p class="service-sub">Some Text</p>
   <img src="path" />
</a>
```

What I want to do is change out the styling in p.service-hub. Here are two methods I've tried, but to no avail...

```
Method 1: a .service-hub *:hover
Method 2: a .service-hub:hover
```

Is this even possible? Because the hover event is first trigged with the A tag, so would it even recognize the hover on p.service-hub?

Comment: Sorry, did not get you. Are you trying to style the `p` tag on `hover` of `a` (or) trying to do something on `hover` of the `p` tag?

Comment: You can easily do it using jQuery.

Comment: Could you assign a `Div id` to `p.serivce-hub` and over write the hover from A in the CSS?

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli Why use _JQuery_ if you can do it with _CSS_ ?

Comment: you have a typo there - use `.service-sub:hover` not `.service-hub:hover`

Comment: Typo? Your CSS targets `service-hub` but the class is `service-sub`. With that fixed method 2 should be what you use.

Comment: Unless you have specified a hover event for the anchor link I see no reason why `a .service-sub:hover` should not work.

If you could make a JSFiddle with some code we might be able to help further. At the moment, we don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: please verify that it's a typo and if so, it'd be great if you could delete the question...

Comment: @ZathrusWriter: I am not sure if OP can delete this question because there are answers already posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
a:hover .service-sub
```

Comment: Ah! That did it. I should have tried that to begin with. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The anchor tag gets the hover pseudo-class, not the `<P>`.

```
a:hover .service-hub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also user `a:hover *` to select all `<a>` children

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following on the specified cases-

```
a:hover p// In case You want to apply some style on all the <p>-tag which are either immediate child or successors of an <a>-tag.
{...}
```

or

```
a:hover p.service-sub// In case You want to apply some style on all the <p>-tag with class-"service-sub" which are either immediate child or successors of an <a>-tag.
{...}
```

or

```
a:hover .service-sub// In case You want to apply some style on all the elements with class-"service-sub" which are either immediate child or successors of an <a>-tag.
{}
```

### For what you want to do use this-

```
a:hover>p.service-sub// In case You want to apply some style on all the <p>-tag with class-"service-sub" which are  child elements of an <a>-tag.
{...}
```